# Python hangs when printing some Unicode c1 control characters, not in a consistent manner

Tags: terminal, linux-mint, freeze, unicode, control-characters

For testing purposes, I created a file with bytes 0xc2 0x90, representing Unicode code point 0x90  in UTF-8 encoding.

I can `cat` this file without an issue, but trying to `print` the string written from it, or the corresponding literal, or the string created in other way...

```
Python 3.8.10 (default, Mar 15 2022, 12:22:08) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print('\x90')
```

results in the terminal hanging. The program doesn't even respond to Ctrl-C.

The same happens for several other individual characters, with no pattern that I can discern.

Even stranger:

```
>>> for i in range(150): print(chr(i))
```

This succeeds, even though one of the characters printed will be the 0x90 character in question. If I end the range at `156` instead, it will hang again, but interruptibly.

I can't find any rhyme or reason to this behaviour. I understand that I am trying to display control characters and that this could potentially cause the terminal output to look strange, for the cursor to jump around etc.; but I don't expect a hard terminal hang. And again, the output differs from what I get when trying to display the characters in other ways (like `cat`).

What is going on, and what should I try next to fix it? I am using the built-in Python 3.8.10 installation on Linux Mint (20.3, Una), kernel version 5.4.0-109-generic.

Comment: A bit more research indicates that 0x90 is [intended to start a sequence of data that will terminate with 0x9c](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#C1_controls). Since UTF-8 is ASCII-transparent, this presumably can be backwards compatible even to really old terminal emulation routines. But I'm still surprised that there is no error, no way to indicate that there is no more data forthcoming, and even ctrl-C doesn't work. Actually, ctrl-D does work, but it also causes Python to quit.

Comment: There is no nonbreaking space in C1, which is decimal 128..159. NBSP is U+00A0 or decimal 160, and is in _G1_ (or was in 2022/8859 days; now it's the Latin-1 Supplemental block) just like original space U+0020 is/was in G0. OTOH on at least _some_ terminals (don't know for Mint) ESCape U+001B and SO,SI U+000E,U+000F affect and may mess up terminal operation.

Comment: re nonbreaking space: Before posting initially, I had mis-identified the character due to careless mental math and/or a failure of short term memory; I thought I'd edited to account for that, but apparently missed a spot. Fixed. The character is indeed in C1; it is not a non-breaking space.

Comment: Note: `echo -e "\e[7m TEST \e[0m"` will give the same result as `echo -e "\x9b7m TEST \x9b0m"` in SOME terminals (true for e.g. AmigaShell, ECMA-Latin-1, ISO 8859-01), Character 9B (hex) is "CSI" (Command Sequence Introducer) in that case. Might be this is what is creating the problem here?

Comment: It does not in my case; `echo` shows the 9b character with a replacement glyph. Regardless I'm not sure exactly how that would connect to my question. What I'm wondering about is the hang and the relative inability to do anything about it. Python knows where the end of the string is, after all.

Comment: See https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-terminal/-/issues/256 and https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=730154.

Comment: "but I don't expect a hard terminal hang" - it's not a hard hang, the terminal is waiting for the escape sequence to terminate. The difference between your `cat` command vs. the python `print()` is presumably that `cat` is followed by the shell printings its prompt, vs. `print()` is followed by python printing its prompt. I guess your shell prompt contains characters that terminate the pending escape sequence.

Comment: "the terminal is waiting for the escape sequence to terminate." It is effectively a hang because *I do not have a means to provide the termination of the sequence*.

Comment: You're driving a terminal emulator, a state machine. It's _your_ responsibility to return to its default parser state if that's what you want to do. If you print any non-printable character, you have to know what it does, whether it enters some special state, and if so then how to leave that state. Alternatively, you should make sure that you only emit printable characters. Surely life would be more convenient if there was a single character that always caused the parser to return to the default state, alas I'm afraid there isn't.

Comment: But why does the *terminal* state prevent *Python* from receiv- *oh wow, it doesn't!* Thanks for the heads-up. I had assumed that not being able to process ctrl-C meant that it also couldn't process ordinary text. Typing `print('\x9c')` and pressing enter allows me to escape after trying `print('\x90')`, although it won't show me what I'm typing.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't clear on this, I thought you'd find it out, and indeed you did. :) Another nice example is to blindly ask python to create a file, then see from another terminal that the file is already there. Python does everything in time, it's just the terminal that "swallows" some of its output.